# Sidebar Content Box not editable

Tags: html, wordpress, widget, wordpress-theming, sidebar

I have built a custom theme for a client some 12 months ago and all was working fine until recently. My client is unable to edit the content in the widgets on his sidebar.
I have tried to add other text widgets to the sidebar and even those are uneditable. 
I disabled all the plugins to see if any of those are the culprit and as such made zero difference. Incidentally all of the text widgets are displaying perfectly on the public side of the website but my client is unable to add or edit and text widget in the sidebar.
Here is a screeny showing whats going on...
[image]

Many thanks for any advice you can give in this.
Phillip Dews

**EDIT**

For those that require it. Here is the code from my custom theme....

functions.php

```
function paradisereloaded_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', 'paradisereloaded' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'description'   => __( 'Add widgets here to appear in your sidebar.', 'paradisereloaded' ),
        'before_widget' => '<section id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</section>',
        'before_title'  => '<h2 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h2>',
    ));
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'paradisereloaded_widgets_init' );
```

And now the

sidebar.php

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for the sidebar containing the main widget area
 *
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage paradisereloaded
* @since Paradise Reloaded 1.0.0
 */
?>

<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' )  ) : ?>
    <aside id="secondary" class="sidebar widget-area" role="complementary">
        <?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
    </aside><!-- .sidebar .widget-area -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: delete those text widget and try to add new one.

Comment: I Cannot do that fella, Cannot risk losing the sidebar as it already is! I instead tried to add a new one and it was exactly the same!

Comment: Did you check your functions.php. Check any hook are blocked?.

Comment: Yep all fully checked and nothing is blocked, you can see the code above. It was working fine up until a month ago when it stopped working! Yes I have also disabled all plugins to see if it was a conflict and nothing was shown there!